# Google AdSense providing a relative advert relating to jQuery

Tags: jquery, adsense

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have a bit of jQuery that randomly generates a sentence on refreshing the page. I want Google ads to generate an advert relative to the sentence.

Does anybody know if this is possible, and if so, how I would go about it?

Any help would be appreciated, being a novice.

Comment: Anything is possible, but something tells me this is against Google's rules, and that you can expect to have your account closed rather quickly if trying to manipulate AdSense like that !

Comment: That's a fair comment, I just wondered if this was possible by following the rules. If not, I'll have to rethink my strategy. I don't fancy having my account closed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Im no Google expert nor have I ever done anything similar @Adeneo, but why is the idea against Googles rules? Isn't that just targeted advertising in a sense?

Comment: I guess nobody knows the answer to this.